# ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to string.

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Okay, I'm making a CD collection Program and everything was going well as I followed along my lesson but then I ran into the problem of wanting to make it show up in the jTextArea. I bet there is a simple solution but I cannot find one. I'm new to this and any answer would be appreciated, I also looked on here for answers but found nothing I understood.

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jButton1.setEnabled(true);
    jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    jButton3.setEnabled(false);
    jButton4.setEnabled(false);      //buttons                                       

    ArrayList<String> CD = new ArrayList();  //list
    Collections.addAll(CD, "\nEd Sheeran - X\n", "\nNirvana - Nevermind\n", "\nShania Twain - Up!\n", "\nLights - Little Machines\n", "\nTaylor Swift - 1989\n");          //PreAdded CDs
    Collections.sort(CD);
    jTextArea1.setText(CD);    //it works if i do System.out.println(CD) ? I need it to go to jTextArea1 though.
```

Comment: What do you think `setText` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: "works if i do `System.out.println(CD)`" have you heard about `toString()` method?

Comment: Im new to this lol. Sorry I don't actually know the meaning of everything to the exact extent

Comment: try using a for loop to run through each String and then append that to the text area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call

```
System.out.println(CD);
```

it equates to this

```
System.out.println(CD.toString());
```

So what you need is

```
jTextArea1.setText(CD.toString());
```

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`, and an [overload of `println` takes an `Object` as a parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-), on which `toString()` is eventually called.  That is why `System.out.println(CD)` works.

In contrast, a `JTextArea` inherits its [`setText()` method from `JTextComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-), and it accepts a `String`, not an `Object`.  An `ArrayList` can't be converted implicitly to a `String`.  You can easily call `toString()` to convert to a `String` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

`setText` expects *one* `String`.  You have a list of many `String`s.  You must decide how to combine those many `String`s into one yourself.

Comment: Or use the rather nice default implementation ([`AbstractCollection.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29)) which gets invoked simply by typing `CD.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

JTextArea takes a `String` parameter, not an `ArrayList`. You will need to convert the CD ArrayList to a String (in whatever method you find optimal) before you proceed.